# Problem with loading module ‘Distribution.Simple’

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, cabal, haskell-stack

I was trying to build one new project in Haskell (GHC version 8.10.4, stack version 2.7.3, cabal version 3.6.2.0) using `stack`, but at the time of running the command `stack setup` I (surprisingly) got the following error:

```
Setup.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Distribution.Simple’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘Cabal-3.2.1.0’.
    You can run ‘:set -package Cabal’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import Distribution.Simple
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, it is worth noting that I was trying to look for different solutions on the Internet, but didn't find the working one for me. The general idea was to explicitly add `Cabal` into the `package.yaml` file here:

```
library:
  source-dirs: src
  dependencies:
    - Cabal
```

But that didn't save my situation. I was able to build the project without that step (well, just skipped that part), but I was interested to solve the issue.

Moreover, when I was trying to build Haskell package `timeit` (as an example, using the command line), there was the same error at the time of executing
`runhaskell Setup.hs configure`.

Interestingly, I didn't have this problem before (probably, it appeared after I updated GHC).

Does anybody know any ways of how to deal with such issue? Is there any way probably to reinstall the GHC, or cabal, or stack (if it helps)? Would be glad to see any comments and solutions.

Comment: This issue looks related: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5412. Do the suggestions there help you? Maybe also check whether your `stack` version is up-to-date.

Comment: @sjakobi, thanks for providing this link, I went through the comments there and I'm not sure if I understand one thing: there was a comment "Luckily, it doesn't break if ```package-db``` is set by ```GHC_PACKAGE_PATH```. so a workaround is to delete ```~/.ghc/*/environments/default``` and set any ```package-db``` directives by environment variable instead." Should I do anything else after deleting mentioned ```default``` file?

Comment: No idea. Maybe you can get better help by commenting on that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Deleting the files

```sh
~/.ghc/*/environments/default
```

(or the whole folder `.ghc`) solved the `stack setup` problem.

It seems that they were somehow interacting with stack's operations.

Comment: is this safe to delete? i just changed the file to a different name and it *did* solve the issue. it would be great to know what the problem was and how this solves it.

Comment: I delete the whole folder .ghc. then my vscode works fine for the haskell lsp.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting the

> ~/.ghc/*/environments/default

file, just add the Cabal package to it, including version number, which you can find if you run the command:

```
ghc-pkg list
```

Comment: Yh, this is the optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

To add Cabal package as dependency in a stack project(as proposed by @ru13r): -

Edit package.yaml and and entry `Cabal` under `dependencies`, like so:

```yaml
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- Cabal
```